# Filling multidimensional list by loop

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops

I have little experience coding, most of what I did was done with VBA and there you have arrays. On python you apparently do not use arrays but lists of lists if I'm not mistaken and I seem to have trouble with these. Here a sample of what I did:

```
array=[["string"]*2]*2
```

So essentially I wanted to create a 2x2 array. This I wanted to fill using a loop, for the minimal example I fill it with a string b+a:

```
for b in range(0,2):
    for a in range(0,2):
        array[b][a]=b,"+",a
        print(array[b][a])

print(array[0][0], array[1][0],array[0][1], array[1][1])
```

The first print command gives what I expected:

```
(0, '+', 0)
(0, '+', 1)
(1, '+', 0)
(1, '+', 1)
```

But the second print command is strange:

```
(1, '+', 0) (1, '+', 0) (1, '+', 1) (1, '+', 1)
```

When printing array[0][0] I would expect to receive (0, '+', 0) but instead I get what I would expect to be array[1][0]. It looks like when using print inside the loop I get the results that I expect but if I print the exact same element outside of the loops I get strange results.

```
array[0][0]
```

should have the exact same content as

```
array[b][a]
```

for when I just started the loop (first print command), no?

I'm sorry I don't really know how to describe the problem more precisely, I hope you see what my problem is.

Comment: do `array=[["string"] for _ in range(2)] for _ in range(2)]`

Comment: Also check your final print: it's not printing in the same order as the loop. Loop does (00,01,10,11)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre missing a `[` in the beginning: `array=[[[""] for _ in range(2)] for _ in range(2)]`

Comment: yes, of course!